# Must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern (CS0501)

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, automatic-properties

Im newbie in C# and don't know its syntax. But I know a bit about other languages (Java, C++).
I downloaded [GLWidget project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glwidget/files/) and tryed to build it. However I got an error CS0501 at these lines (with `{ get; set; }`):

```
namespace Gtk
{
    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class GLWidget : DrawingArea, IDisposable
    {
        IGraphicsContext graphicsContext;
        static int graphicsContextCount;

        /// <summary>Use a single buffer versus a double buffer.</summary>
        [Browsable(true)]
        public bool SingleBuffer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Color Buffer Bits-Per-Pixel</summary>
        public int ColorBPP { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Accumulation Buffer Bits-Per-Pixel</summary>
        public int AccumulatorBPP { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Depth Buffer Bits-Per-Pixel</summary>
        public int DepthBPP { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Stencil Buffer Bits-Per-Pixel</summary>
        public int StencilBPP { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Number of samples</summary>
        public int Samples { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Indicates if steropic renderering is enabled</summary>
        public bool Stereo { get; set; }

        IWindowInfo windowInfo;
```

Why did this guy do that? Is it a trivial error or not?

Comment: What version of .NET did you use too compile it? The get; set; syntax hasn't always been around.

Comment: Your compiler has to understand .NET 3.5 (or 4.0?) syntax. Visual Studio 2010 can do that, even if targeting .NET 2.0.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .NET version. It is a C# version issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of the compiler are you using? This code is using [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)  which are available in C# 3.0 and later.

Since I'm assuming MonoDevelop uses the [Mono compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) 'mcs' (and varients), this problem depends on the version of Mono. Mono 2.6 has support for C# 3.0 (and a preview of 4.0). Perhaps you just need to upgrade Mono and/or MonoDevelop.

Comment: How I have said I am newbie in C#. I downloaded Monodevelopment IDE and that is it.

Comment: How to know what is the .NET version? Where is compiler? I use Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Automatic properties was introduced in c# 3.0, so try to change framework version.

Comment: As Jonathon Reinhart noted in a comment above, it's not a matter of the framework version, but of the compiler version.